# Cannot Scatter, Plot, Show() In While Loop

Tags: python

```
import math
import pylab as plt
import numpy
from numpy import sqrt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import random

numpy.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
def integrand (x):
    return sqrt(1-x**2)
    
q1area, err = quad(integrand,0,1)

print "This program estimates the convergence of Pi to a ratio of one."
while True:
    print "Please choose from one of the five following options:"
    print " 1. 10^1\n 2. 10^2\n 3. 10^3\n"
    choice = int(raw_input())
    options = {1,2,3}
        
    if choice == 1:
        plt.xlim([0,15])
        plt.ylim([-5,5])

        x = numpy.linspace(0,15,500)
        y = numpy.sqrt(1-x**2)
        z = 1+x*0
        
        xcord = []
        ycord = []
        under = []
        above = []
        pratiolist = []
        yvalues = []
        xvalues = range(1,11)

        for i in range(10):
            xcord.append(random.random())
            ycord.append(random.random())

        for j in ycord:
            if (j <= q1area):
                under.append(1)
    
            else:
                above.append(1)
                
            punder = len(under)
            if punder == 0:
                punder = punder + 1
            
            pabove = len(above)
            if pabove == 0:
                pabove = pabove + 1
            
            pratio = punder / float(pabove)
            pratiolist.append(pratio)
            
        for k in pratiolist:
            rtpi = k / float(math.pi)
            yvalues.append(rtpi)
        
        plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
        plt.plot(x,z,'g')
        plt.show()
        
    if choice == 2:
        plt.xlim([0,110])
        plt.ylim([-5,5])

        x = numpy.linspace(0,110,500)
        y = numpy.sqrt(1-x**2)
        z = 1+x*0
        
        xcord = []
        ycord = []
        under = []
        above = []
        pratiolist = []
        yvalues = []
        xvalues = range(1,101)

        for i in range(100):
            xcord.append(random.random())
            ycord.append(random.random())

        for j in ycord:
            if (j <= q1area):
                under.append(1)
    
            else:
                above.append(1)
                
            punder = len(under)
            if punder == 0:
                punder = punder + 1
            
            pabove = len(above)
            if pabove == 0:
                pabove = pabove + 1
            
            pratio = punder / float(pabove)
            pratiolist.append(pratio)
            
        for k in pratiolist:
            rtpi = k / float(math.pi)
            yvalues.append(rtpi)
        
        plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
        plt.plot(x,z,'g')
        plt.show()
        
    if choice == 3:
        plt.xlim([0,1100])
        plt.ylim([-5,5])

        x = numpy.linspace(0,1100,500)
        y = numpy.sqrt(1-x**2)
        z = 1+x*0
        
        xcord = []
        ycord = []
        under = []
        above = []
        pratiolist = []
        yvalues = []
        xvalues = range(1,1001)

        for i in range(1000):
            xcord.append(random.random())
            ycord.append(random.random())

        for j in ycord:
            if (j <= q1area):
                under.append(1)
    
            else:
                above.append(1)
                
            punder = len(under)
            if punder == 0:
                punder = punder + 1
            
            pabove = len(above)
            if pabove == 0:
                pabove = pabove + 1
            
            pratio = punder / float(pabove)
            pratiolist.append(pratio)
            
        for k in pratiolist:
            rtpi = k / float(math.pi)
            yvalues.append(rtpi)
            
        plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
        plt.plot(x,z,'g')
        plt.show()
        
    while choice not in options:
        print "Not a valid choice!\n"
        break
        
#plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
#plt.plot(x,z,'g')
#plt.show()
```

The only way I can get the graphs to show is if I place break statements at the end of every if choice == 1,2,3, etc. and then place:

```
plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
plt.plot(x,z,'g')
plt.show()
```

At the bottom of my code. This is inconvenient, I would like my to loop endlessly allowing choice between 1,2,3 without having to rerun the program. Why does Python's graphs crash when they are in whiles?

## UPDATE

By using plt.draw(), I was able to get the graph to at least show but it still is not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by not responding you mean it doesn't show the prompt again this is because plt.show() will cause the program to stop until the window is closed. You can replace the plt.show()'s with plt.draw(), but to actually have windows come up you need to be in interactive mode. This is accomplished by calling plt.ion() sometime before any of the draw calls (I put it before the while True:). I've tested it an this should accomplish the behavior you're looking for.

Edit: Since you aren't redrawing the same data, calling draw() will append the data to the specific plot (i.e. typing 1 in over and over will keep adding points). I don't know what type of behavior you're looking for but you may want to call plt.clf before each scatter call if you want to clear the figure.

Comment: Doing it this way accomplishes very little. Nothing actually that I don't already have an issue with. The graph crashes and the kernel crashes from doing it this way. All I want is to be able to select one of my three graphs to be displayed at a time. But I want this in a loop so I don't have to restart the program every time.

Comment: Doing it like [this](http://pastebin.com/rHpZtAf4) worked perfectly for me with no crashes. What error is output on crash?

Comment: It literally causes the window to not respond. Ctrl+Alt+Del to close the window and restart the crashed kernel in Canopy.

Comment: And you tried the version I linked? It works no problem for me if I run it from command line python [filename]